# Data reporting, visualization and warehousing

Tags: mysql, mongodb, hadoop, solr, database

I'm using mysql for my database needs and the total size is ~1.5 TB.

I'm looking for a [Business intelligence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_intelligence) tool which gives me an interface to fetch reports in any desired format to help decision making. The user shall be able to sum, sort, count, sum in various ways.

I don't know what shall I do about it.

In the past few days, I've read dozen of articles and watched many videos about Bigdata, hadoop, BIRT, Solr, Cassandra, mongodb, noSql and just everything that popped in search suggestions for my queries on BI but can't decide what's the right tool for me.

Is there a tool available to help me with my Data reporting and visualizing needs?

Answer (score 2):

Did you read about Tableau (http://www.tableausoftware.com/)? Its a very nice data visualization tool (though not free but worth it) and can connect to various data sources (mysql, hive etc). Also it provides options to do all such operations you mentioned. It will be worth to evaluate it once.

It provides a 15 day free version. You can try out and see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try Google Big Query, it should solve your issue
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/

For syntax, please refer
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference

Comment: It is sensitive data. I wouldn't want to upload it to google.